# CDF or area under the curve for a bivariate normal distribution in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the cumulative density function for a bivariate normal distribution consisting of two continuous variables that are correlated. I want to do so without making use of external add-ons. The ultimate goal is to calculate the area under the curve for a given set of intervals (e.g., `0 < X < 1, 0 < Y < 1`). Yes, these calculations must be performed in Excel.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ehm0mclZs54) helped me to calculate the PDF for any given set of values, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think this question fits better at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I disagree. This task is trivial in statistical software packages (such as R or Python). This question is directly related to how to do it in Excel, not the underlying stats.

Comment: Excel is not R or Python. Anyways, have you tried using [NORM.DIST function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/norm-dist-function-edb1cc14-a21c-4e53-839d-8082074c9f8d)?

Comment: Yes, but that is for a univariate normal distribution. My question is specifically regarding a bivariate distribution.